# Вывод дополнительной информации из массива данных

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите решить такую задачу:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var routes = {
     1: {
     B1: ['1ME21х59', '1ME20х18'],
     B2: ['2ME21х59', '2ME22х37'],
     B3: ['3ME22х33', '3ME22х36'],
     B4: ['4ME22х33', '4ME22х36'],
     B5: ['5ME22х17', '5ME22х16'],
     B6: ['6ME22х41', '6ME22х13']
   },
   
   2: {
     B1: ['1ME20х19', '1ME22х15'],
     B2: ['2ME21х73', '2ME21х69'],
     B3: ['3ME22х13', '3ME22х14'],
     B4: ['4ME22х13', '4ME22х16'],
     B5: ['5ME22х14', '5ME22х13'],
     B6: ['6ME22х15', '6ME22х16']
   },
   
   3: {
     B1: ['1ME20х20', '1MD23G02'],
     B2: ['2ME21х86', '2ME21х73'],
     B3: ['3ME22х15', '3ME22х16'],
     B4: ['4ME22х17', '4ME22х15'],
     B5: ['5ME22х20', '5ME22х21'],
     B6: ['6ME22х20', '6ME22х22']
   }   
 };
 
 // указываем номер маршрута (в ручную)
 var route = 2;
 $('#route').text(route);
 
 // выбираем индексы для отображения
 out = [];
    out.push(routes[route].B1[0]);
    $('.B11').html(out);
    out = [];
    out.push(routes[route].B1[1]);
    $('.B12').html(out); 

    // массив с подробной информацией
    var indexEquip = {
      '1ME20х19': ['МЗ', '3.6'],
      '1ME22х15': ['РО', '19.0']        
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  <div class="routeWrapper">
    Индекс - <span class="route B11"></span><br />
    Индекс - <span class="route B12"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="route-info">
    Имя - <span></span><br />
    Значение - <span></span>
  </div>
```

Вывожу индексы на страницу из массива routes. Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на выведенный индекс, отображалась более подробная информация, относящаяся к соответствующему индексу из другого массива indexEquip.

Comment: `1ME20х19: {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'}`, может вы имели в виду `1ME20х19: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']`? И надо все элементы `bN` проверить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Да, ссори, но не в этом суть. Исправлю. Спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy я же написал, что мне нужно, пример кода который выбирает первый массив? Я думаю, что тут будет лишним. Там таких массивов от 1 до 42, в зависимости от условий (дата, время, и т.д.) получаю номер (к примеру "16"), которому соответствует массив в вопросе. Долее вывожу данные из него. Но мне нужно, получить  подробную информацию из другого массива, которая соответствует полученным ранее "ME" как в примере. Точнее всем 12. И вывести соответсвующие значения.

Comment: номеру 16 соответствует не массив, что именно ожидается получить в конце - непонятно, _мне нужно отобразить_ - ни о чем не говорит, может достаточно просто эти восемь цифр сразу в консоль вывести. где именно эти данные расположены, непонятно. То есть сейчас, кроме вас **никто** не знает что именно у вас есть и что вы хотите получить. В принципе на ваш вопрос можно также обще ответить как он задан: _пробегитесь циклом по выбранным элементам и выведите их_

Comment: @Grundy дополнил вопрос

Comment: добавьте [mcve], чтобы было понятно **что уже готово** и **что нужно получить**

Comment: @VasilyUK, мало дополнили, фактически новой информации не появилось, кроме того что вместо цифр выводите строки

Comment: @Grundy попытался выкинуть всё лишнее и показать что есть. [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/vasilk0v/epoa4ona/1/)

Comment: @VasilyUK, можно было еще больше убрать, и не увидел в коде объекта из которого надо значения выводить, и собственно как они должны выглядеть при выводе тоже непонятно

Comment: вообще: значение элемента в массиве `B1` - это ключи объекта, поэтому значение получается простым обращением к полю объекта `obj[B1[0]]` Например. Более общее решение есть в ответе

Comment: @Grundy переписал вопрос - добавил код с уже предложенным решением, уточнил что мне нужно на выходе. Спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy я не могу понять, за что меня минусуют?? Пять раз переписал вопрос и название вопроса... И решение уже нашел (не здесь), так как только минусы летят. Если не можете или не понятно - напишите в комментах и идите дальше, искать понятные вопросы. "Спасибо"!!!

Comment: вам нужно проявить терпение. Не принимайте минусы на свой счет, они относятся только к вопросу.

Comment: @VasilyUK, ваш вопрос из разряда "_сделайте за меня_", к тому же еще и сформулированный не четко. Сообщество не любит такие вопросы -- отсюда и минусы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделано чисто для наглядности алгоритма, ответ можно улучшать и улучшать.

Перебирает все элементы объекта `obj1`, его под-элементов, и сами массивы этих под элементов. Чем больше элементов, тем больше время выполнения.

```js
var obj1 = {
    16: {
        B1: ['1ME20х19', '1ME22х15'],
        B2: ['2ME21х73', '2ME21х69'],
        B3: ['3ME22х13', '3ME22х14'],
        B4: ['4ME22х13', '4ME22х16'],
        B5: ['5ME22х14', '5ME22х13'],
        B6: ['6ME22х15', '6ME22х16'],
        RY: ['T2PTY100P']
    }
};

var obj2 = {
    '1ME20х19': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    '6ME22х15': [9, 10, 54, 2, 3, 4, 5]
};

var newObj = {};

for (var key in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var inObj = obj1[key];
        for (var inKey in inObj) {
            if (inObj.hasOwnProperty(inKey)) {
                var arrays = inObj[inKey];
                var i = arrays.length;
                while (i--) {
                    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(arrays[i])) {
                        newObj[arrays[i]] = obj2[arrays[i]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: уточню немного - мне нужно вывести на страницу в таком виде: Индекс системы: 1ME20х19, место: 1, индекс места: 2, отм.: 3, помещение: 4, установка: 5, питание: 6, громкоговоритель: 7, ПСС: 8.

Comment: @VasilyUK что не работает в вашем коде? Какие входные данные у вас есть, вид двух объектов добавьте тогда. А индексы массива не играют большую роль, их можно сортировать или добавлять как угодно

Comment: переписал вопрос - добавил код с уже предложенным тобой решением, уточнил что мне нужно на выходе. Спасибо!

Comment: @VasilyUK из того, что вы добавили в вопрос, я ничего не понял))) Ошибка в чем? в неверном массиве? По подробнее опишите. Да и мой код вроде как отработал верно. Если ошибка в порядке элементов массива, это потому что я считаю массив с конца, а не с начала

Comment: Нет! Вашей ошибки нет. Я вижу что выводится то, что мне нужно. Я прошу помочь вывести мне эти данные в таком виде как я привел в примере. Не в целой массе, а так, чтобы ими можно было "играться". Чёт я ни как не могу справиться с этим. Спасибо!

Comment: @VasilyUK тогда поясняйте, что значит `играться`, и (наверное) текстовый вариант того, что хотите получить из нового полученного объекта

Comment: @VasilyUK ааа, надо вывести данные нужного свойства что ли? А выводятся только свойства без данных?

Comment: "играться" - это к примеру взять только одно значение конкретного индекса (<span class="type">КВ-1Р</span>) и т.д.

Comment: @VasilyUK дак, если вы будите знать значение этого индекса, то почему бы его не взять. Тут уже вы сами должны сделать логику того, что нужно показывать. Я не могу вам в этом помочь

Comment: @VasilyUK ответ перестал быть верным? или вести вас в верном направлении? Какова причина снятия его как правильный?